# File walk with exclusions and regex

Tags: python-2.7, os.walk

```
import os

root = "C:\\temp\\a"
exclude = set(["New folder"])


for current, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
  dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
  for f in files:
    print f
```

How can I make sure I also exclude case and white space variants of "New folder"
ie

```
exclude = set([
 "New folder",
 "New Folder",
 "new folder",
 "new Folder",
 "newfolder"
 ])
```

without having to work out all possible variants as part of the exclusion set? Can this be plugged in to to a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has fully featured regex implemented in the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). You can precompile a regex and match it to each directory name:

```
import os, re

root = "C:\\temp\\a"
exclude = re.compile('^new\\s*folder$', re.IGNORECASE)

for current, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
  dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if exclude.match(d) is not None]
  for f in files:
    print f
```

The regular expression is precompiled since you are using it many times. It has the following components:

- `^`, `$`  means the beginning and end of the string, respectively. This is necessary to avoid partial matches such as `a new folder!`.
- `\\s*` means zero or more spaces of any kind. You can replace this with `*` if you want to check strictly for space characters.
- The flag `e.IGNORECASE` makes the comparison case insensitive, so that it matches all of your original possibilities. As a side effect, this will also match things like `NeWfOlDeR`.

Comment: Yes. Regex are awesome if you use them properly. I'm glad you like it.